# Geometric sequence excercise.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A geometric sequence has the first term as $48$ , with common ratio as $0.6$ .
How to calculate $\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}U_{n}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_1r^n = \frac{u_1}{1 - r} ; |r|< 1$$

Given this we first express your problem mathematically
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty u_n $$
where $u_n = 48(0.6)^{n-1}$ and $u_4 = 10.368$
$$\sum_{n=4}^\infty u_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_{n+4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_4(0.6)^n $$
$$=\frac{10.368}{0.4} = 25.92$$

Comment: Thank tou so much , The truyh is that I just want to compare the result with my answer . I em so lucky when have a same result . Thank you one more time

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the $n$ first terms of a geometric sequence of first term $a$ and of ratio $r$ is : $$\sum_{i=0}^nU_i=a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
Thus to solve your question :
$$\sum_{i=4}^\infty U_i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty U_i-\sum_{i=0}^3 U_i=48\frac{1}{1-0.6}-48\frac{1-0.6^3}{1-0.6}=48\frac{0.6^3}{0.4}=25.92$$
Note since $r<1$ : $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty U_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^nU_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=a\frac{1}{1-r}$$